# Не завершается выплнение программы

Tags: c

Данная программа получает команды из командной строки и выполняет работу. После получения строки "stop", она должна завершить выполнение, но этого не происходит. Скажите пожалуйста, что не так?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIZE_BUFF 127

void main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{
    char str[SIZE_BUFF];
    char *arg[3];
    arg[2] = NULL;
    char *name_prog = NULL;
    char *options = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    int status = 0;
    while(1){
        printf("%s$", getenv("USER"));

        fgets(str, 10, stdin);

        if(strlen(str) > SIZE_BUFF){
            printf("ERROR!\n");
            continue;
        }

        if(!strcmp(str, "stop"))
            exit(0);


        for(i = 0; (str[i] != ' ') && (str[i] != '\0'); i++);

        strncpy(name_prog = realloc(name_prog, sizeof(char)*(i + 1)), str, i);
        *(name_prog + i) = '\0';
        arg[0] = name_prog;
        if(i == strlen(str)) {
            arg[1] = NULL;
        }
        else {
            strncpy(options = realloc(options, (strlen(str) - i + 1)), str + i + 1, strlen(str) - i);
            *(options + strlen(str) - i) = '\0';
            arg[1] = options;
        }

        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0){
            execvp(name_prog,arg);
            system("ps");
        } else if(pid > 0){
            wait(&status);
            printf("RESU: %i\n", status);
        }

    }
    free(name_prog);
}
```

Comment: `if(strlen(str) > SIZE_BUFF){` - это как это такое могло получиться, если `SIZE_BUFF` равен `127`, а в `fgets` вы передаете предел и того меньше - `10`? Защита от глюка, вызванного от попадание высокоскоростной космической частицы?

Answer (score 2):

Читаем описание `fgets` и с удивлением обнаруживаем, что она, оказывается, пишет в буфер и символ новой строки тоже...

> *Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.*

[Отсюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).